# SwiftUI searchbar

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm trying to build an App which can display different pdfs via sheet. So far so good, but I want the user to be able to filter the Button which triggers the sheet modifier via a searchbar. This is what doesn't work for me. I tried different solutions from web and Stack Overflow, but none of them worked for me. I think I have to filter the Text from the Buttons which trigger the Boolean for sheet. But how? With a List or a ForEach I can't Buttons with every time different var/Bool.

Below is my Searchbar class, with just a List and filtered it works.

```
class SearchBar: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    
    
    let searchController: UISearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    
    @Binding var text: String
    let hide : Bool
    let placeholder : String
    let cancelButton : Bool
    let autocapitalization : UITextAutocapitalizationType
    
    init(text: Binding<String>, hide: Bool, placeholder: String, cancelButton: Bool, autocapitalization: UITextAutocapitalizationType) {
        
        self._text = text
        self.hide = hide
        self.placeholder = placeholder
        self.cancelButton = cancelButton
        self.autocapitalization = autocapitalization
        
        super.init()
        
        
        self.searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        
        self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = hide
        self.searchController.automaticallyShowsCancelButton = cancelButton
        self.searchController.searchBar.placeholder = placeholder
        self.searchController.searchBar.autocapitalizationType = autocapitalization
        
    }
}

extension SearchBar: UISearchResultsUpdating {
   
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        
        // Publish search bar text changes.
        if let searchBarText = searchController.searchBar.text {
            self.text = searchBarText
        }
    }
}

struct SearchBarModifier: ViewModifier {
    
    let searchBar: SearchBar
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .overlay(
                ViewControllerResolver { viewController in
                    viewController.navigationItem.searchController = self.searchBar.searchController
                }
                    .frame(width: 0, height: 0)
            )
    }
}

extension View {
    
    func add(_ searchBar: SearchBar) -> some View {
        return self.modifier(SearchBarModifier(searchBar: searchBar))
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to replace the Binding with an action which calls a closure and passes the entered text.

Replace the line `@Binding var text: String` with

```
var action : ((String) -> Void)?
```

Replace `updateSearchResults` with

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    if let searchBarText = searchController.searchBar.text {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {  self.action?(searchBarText) }
    }
}
```

and the ViewModifier and the view extension with

```
struct SearchBarModifier: ViewModifier {
    
    let searchBar: SearchBar
    let action : ((String) -> Void)?
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .overlay(
                ViewControllerResolver { viewController in
                    searchBar.action = action
                    viewController.navigationItem.searchController = self.searchBar.searchController
                }
                .frame(width: 0, height: 0)
            )
    }
}

extension View {
   func add(_ searchBar: SearchBar, action : ((String) -> Void)?) -> some View {
       return self.modifier(SearchBarModifier(searchBar: searchBar, action: action))
   }
}
```

---

In the view you can add the search bar with

```
.add(self.searchBar, action: { query in
    // do something with query
})
```

Any time the user presses a key the closure is being called.

If you want to call the closure once when the user presses the Search/Go key you have to implement `searchBarSearchButtonClicked` and add another action.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this. But the .add modifier is on a VStack with the Buttons in it, so what should I do with query? Maybe I'm a bit lost actually

Comment: An efficient way is to filter the data in a view model conforming to `ObservableObject`. In this class create a @Published property and set it in the searchbar closure. Return the filtered data in another @Published property which causes the view to reload.